# ngx-slick carousel in angular 4 is not moving item

Tags: angular, typescript, carousel, slick.js

I am new to angular and I want to make the carousel that have the active item in the center like this:
[image: lul pic]

I have read about [slick carousel for angular 2 or higher](https://github.com/devmark/ngx-slick)

I have tried to copy the [example](https://embed.plnkr.co/fblxzfPneL66950A4VDM/) and I have followed the instruction but I am getting this error:

> ERROR TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function

1. I have added the module and imported it on my `app.module`
2. I have added the css and the js to `angular-cli.json`

   ```
   "styles": [
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   "theme.scss",
   "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
   "../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css",
   "../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css"
   ],
   "scripts": [
     "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
     "../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js"
   ],
   ```

This is my module:

```
   ...
   import { SlickModule } from 'ngx-slick';
   import { SliderComponent } from './home/slider/slider.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ... ,
    SliderComponent,   

  ],
  imports: [
    ... ,
    SlickModule.forRoot()

   ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my view:

```
<h2>slider here </h2>

<ngx-slick class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-modal" [config]="slideConfig" 
(afterChange)="afterChange($event)">
  <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
    <img src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
  </div>
</ngx-slick>

<button (click)="addSlide()">Add</button>
<button (click)="removeSlide()">Remove</button> 
<button (click)="slickModal.slickGoTo(2)">slickGoto 2</button>
<button (click)="slickModal.unslick()">unslick</button>
```

and this is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  slides = [
    { img: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/000000' },
    { img: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/111111' },
    { img: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/222222' },
    { img: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/333333' },
    { img: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/444444' },
    { img: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/555555' }
  ];

  slideConfig = { 'slidesToShow': 4, 'slidesToScroll': 4 };

  addSlide() {
    this.slides.push({ img: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/666666' })
  }

  removeSlide() {
    this.slides.length = this.slides.length - 1;
  }

  afterChange(e) {
    console.log('afterChange', e);
  }
}
```

Is this about the jquery that is used in typescript?
Or maybe give me some reference for the carousel just like the *lul pic* I made.

Comment: try using swipper , it works very well for me. https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-swiper-wrapper

Comment: [Please Check this Page. It maybe help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719439/how-to-use-coverflow-or-slick-slider-in-angular2)

Comment: If you are using `ng serve` to start your application, try terminating the process and restart with `ng serve` so that the changes in angular-cli.js are included

Answer (score 6):

Replace your slideConfig with below code:

```
slideConfig = {
    "slidesToShow": 1,
    "slidesToScroll": 1,
    "dots": true,
    "infinite": true,
    "autoplay": true,
    "autoplaySpeed": 1500
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/slick-carousel@1.6.0/slick/slick.js"></script>
```

Lib scripts you must move to index.html. 
In `angular-cli.json` it's not work :(

Comment: I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I tried it , and got it working , Move its location to index.html and it will work.

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/slick-carousel@1.6.0/slick/slick.js"></script>
```