# Angular2 slick carousel

Tags: angular, carousel, slick.js

Is there a tutorial to create an ANGULAR2 [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) component.

Or at least can anyone help me include jQuery and slick carousel script in ANGULAR2.

Answer (score 5):

1. To install slick over npm you can refer to the [original documentation](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) or just run

`npm install slick-carousel`

in your project directory and npm will resolve jquery dependency as well.

2. Include jquery and slick libraries

   - If you are using angular-cli, then include libraries in angular-cli.json file:

     `...
     "scripts": [
     "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
     "../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"
     ],
     ...`
   - also you can include libraries directly in `index.html` file
   - or use some other options
3. Refer to [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137285/slick-carousel-with-angular-2) on how to create a slick-slider component.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look into [ngx-drag-scroll](https://github.com/bfwg/ngx-drag-scroll), it has features like mouse drag to scroll and hide scrollbar etc.

Usage example:

```
<div drag-scroll drag-scroll-y-disabled="true" scrollbar-hidden="true" >
  <img *ngFor="let image of imagelist" [src]="'you_assets_path' + image" />
</div>
```

[image: Scroll]

For more documentation, there a demo site: https://github.com/bfwg/ngx-drag-scroll

Comment: can it work to show text content or basically say a material card component one per slide?

Comment: yeah, if the width of your material card component is the same as the width of your carousel component.

Comment: ok thats for number of cards per view. how about non image data ?

Comment: You can put them in a div and give a fixed with to the div as well.

Comment: Nice! Although could be limited for some use cases. There is a bit more extended swiper: https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-swiper-wrapper